# Query not using proper indexes, slow

Tags: mysql, join, database-indexes

I have the following query in my application:

```
SELECT a.*, f.*
FROM flights_database f 
JOIN airports a ON f.airport = a.airportNameClean
WHERE f.flight_date > CURDATE()-30
AND (f.flight_number LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airport LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airline LIKE 'New York%' OR a.iata = 'New York') 
ORDER by f.flight_date DESC, f.scheme DESC 
LIMIT 200
```

It takes too long to execute (more than a 2 seconds). I have indexes on flight_date, flight_number, airport, airline and scheme.

Still, EXPLAIN reports the following:

```
1
SIMPLE
f
ALL
flight_number,airport,airline,flight_date,auto_suggest,suggest_daily,flight_search
NULL
NULL
NULL
1408614
Using where; Using filesort

1
SIMPLE
a
ref
PRIMARY,airportNameClean
airportNameClean
107
my_db.f.airport
1
Using where
```

Which indexes do I have to create, what am I missing?

Comment: do you mean this `OR a.iata = 'New York%'` like that `OR a.iata LIKE 'New York%'`

Comment: how many rows ya got in your tables

Comment: Airports has got 2000 rows, flights_database around 1.5 million. @echo_me that's a type, I'll edit

Comment: create a composite covered index. it can pull it out of the index and wont need to go to the data pages

Comment: Whar is curdate() - 30 ?!? 30 what? interval 30 day? The combination with `or` is a index killer.

Comment: @flaschenpost It is? It's supposed to SELECT only in the last 30 days

Comment: curdate() - 30 is just some number which is really smaller than most dates. curdate() - interval 30 day is what you want. Then it could make sense for mysql and the optimizer and the simple date-index. just try select `curdate() - 30` and try `curdate() - 30 < '2013-05-20'` and so on, it is really easy to try out those parts of a query.

Comment: Thanks, but obviously that is not the cause of the performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT a.*, f.*
 FROM flights_database f 
 JOIN airports a ON f.airport = a.airportNameClean
 WHERE f.flight_number LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airport LIKE 'New York%' OR f.airline LIKE 'New York%' OR a.iata LIKE 'New York%'
 HAVING f.flight_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 ORDER by f.flight_date DESC, f.scheme DESC 
 LIMIT 200
```

do this index :

```
ALTER TABLE flights_database ADD INDEX myindex (`flight_number`,airport,airline)
```

Comment: Still takes 1.5 seconds, which I find too long. Wait, now trying your second (edited) answer

Comment: Seconds answer takes 1.6 seconds. I would doubt that changing CURADATE()-30 to what you state would help.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of a FOREIGN KEY, which is only available with the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: I use InnoDB. On which columns are you suggesting foreign key. I doubt a foreign key is used for performance reasons?

Comment: can you try this just to see how many seconds you will get :)
try remove this from your query
`OR a.iata = 'New York'`

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, MySQL can only use **one single index** per participating table. In your query, only tables `flights_database` and `airports` are referenced, so it can use exactly 2 indexes. Better make them count  :)

You need to define some multicolumn indexes, on top of your existing single-column ones, finetuned specifically for slow queries. Don't worry about negative performance impact too much, it'll slow down manipulations only, and enhance read operations immensely. Set the indexes so that they provide the most generic filters first (probably on `airport` first, and then right down to the other filters and the sort criteriums.

For `flights_database` you probably want an index on `(airport, airline, flight_number, flight_date)`. It should greatly improve the query time right away.

Comment: Will try. Does the order of the columns in a multicolumn index effect performance that much? Also shouldn't I add scheme too because it is in the ORDER BY clause? And why flight_date as the last one while it is the second one from the beginning of the query.

Comment: Most definitely - the order defines the internal sorting. If you put the `flight_date` first (it's probably unique) the other columns have no point because they only matter in case of duplicates in the first columns. Compare it to a phone book, and think of it as being a single index on `(lastname, initials, address, phonenumber)` - it's obvious that reversing them would make it useless.

Comment: flight_date is not remotely unique. On every flight_date there are thousands of flights. And there are some duplicates possible that have the same scheme time, like codeshare flights.

Comment: I was assuming it also contained the time. Doesn't matter though, the principle stands that you must add an index that specifically helps this query by following the principle I outlined.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the index you provided, query's seem to taken even longer (2.6) seconds. I did try a lot of indexes myself, didn't improve. strange

Comment: Add one on `(flight_date, airport, airline, flight_number)`, it makes more sense with the `flight_date` being just the date as you described, since it's both the main filter and the sort criterium it ought to help a lot. If that doesn't help either I'm more tempted to think it's just memory or I/O problems on the DB server  :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30655/discussion-between-edwardmp-and-niels-keurentjes)